# find and rsync?

Tags: bash, shell, find, pipe, rsync

I want to be able to search for files over 14 days and over 10k and than rsync those found files to a destination.

Is there a way to combine these two commands?

```
find ./ -mtime +14 -size +10k 
rsync --remove-sent-files -avz /src /dest
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can send the output of find into rsync using one of the options outlined below.

#### Method #1

These 2 options are very similar, they both assume you're changing directories to some location and then running the `find` command from there.

```
$ rsync -avz --remove-sent-files \
        --files-from=<(find ./ -mtime +14 -size +10k) ./ /dest
```

You can also use a pipe to feed the list in:

```
$ find ./ -mtime +14 -size +10k -print0 \
        | rsync -av --files-from=- --from0 ./ /dest
```

#### Method #2

This method can be run from anywhere.

```
$ find /src/dir/ -mtime +14 -size +10k -printf %P\\0 \
        | rsync -av --files-from=- --from0 /src/dir/ /dst/dir/
```

- `printf %P`: File's name with the name of the command line argument under which it was found removed. This way, you can use any src directory, no need to cd into your src directory first.

#### References

- [Terminal - rsync + find - commandlinefu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1481/rsync-find)

Comment: This is another working example ```rsync -haviHn --stats --progress --files-from=<(find /mnt/my-files -mtime 0 -printf "%p\n") / /mnt/backup-disk/``` Find will return an absolute path so you need to set / as the copy source

Comment: How to apply the above for photos, with the date the photo was taken (via EXIF / meta data) ? E.g., utilizing `identify -verbose IMG_20200430_113445.jpg | grep -i date` and `exif:DateTime`.