# Want to use find with rsync in script

Tags: shell-script, find, cron, rsync

I'm trying to make a script that will run in cron, that will search a path for specific file name. In the path there might be more folders with that same file name. If found and they are newer than 2 days, rsync the parent folder and all content. This part works but only syncs "filename.txt" that is newer than 2 days and nothing else:

```
#!/bin/sh
find /path/ -name "filename.txt" -type f -mmin -$((60*48)) -exec rsync --ignore-exsiting -az --log-file=/path/ {} /source /destination \;
```

Comment: See this : [find and rsync?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87022/7286)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming by *parent folder* you just mean the folder with filename.txt.

You can get find to print this folder name with `-printf '%h\n'` instead of
the -exec. You can pipe this into a shell loop or xargs for example:

```
find /path/ -name "filename.txt" -type f -mtime -2 -printf '%h\n' |
  xargs -i rsync ... {} /destination \;
```

I think you need to add `-R` to your rsync, else all the
directories will be superimposed at the destination.