# find -exec: add arguments between {} and +

Tags: find, arguments

I want to use find to locate files, then copy those to a directory, so I tried:

```bsh
find . -name '*.png' -exec cp {} /tmp/dest +
```

However, this fails with

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

When I replace the `+` by a `;` it works, but invokes cp for every file individually.  How can I add a trailing argument (such as a destination directory) when using the `+` form of `-exec`?

Of course, in this case I can work around the apparent limitation by using `cp -t` (such as indicated in [this post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12060557/974555), but that solution is specific to `cp`.  Instead, I might be using rsync, scp, or some other tool.  Is there a general way to add arguments between `{}` and `+` in `find -exec`?

Comment: `cp -t /tmp/dest {} +`

Comment: @nezabudka I already mentioned that workaround in the question, it works for `cp` but may not work for other applications where I may need a similar syntax.

Comment: As an aside consider xargs when the find will return multiple files https://danielmiessler.com/blog/linux-xargs-vs-exec/#:~:text=When%20you%20use%20%2Dexec%20to,which%20is%20often%20just%20once.

Comment: @StephenBoston That blog post specifically deals with the `-exec ... \;` usage of `-exec`, and does not consider `-exec ... {} +`, which would not execute the utility more than once per batch, just like `xargs` would.  This question is about the `-exec ... {} +` usage and syntax specifically.

Comment: Most commands that take a variable number of args specify they shall be given last. `mv` and `cp` were historical anomalies that took a directory last, and were fixed so they worked with xargs. I can't offhand think of any other such anomalies.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant What if I want to copy with `rsync` rather than cp? For example, `rsync src1 src2 src3 src4 user@host:dest/`?  `rsync --help | grep target` comes up empty.  Same for `scp`.

Comment: You send the filenames from `find -print0` and pipe them into `rsync --files-from=- --from0`. They don't appear on the command line at all, so this fixes both the args order and the max-args limit. I found this at `https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87018/find-and-rsync`.

Comment: I never got the hang of scp. I use ssh, variations based on `( cd /src && tar czf - . ) | ssh usr@host '( cd /dst && tar xzf - )'`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, if you're using `-exec ... {} +`, there may be nothing between `{}` and `+` apart from whitespace. There is no way around that.

From the POSIX standard specification of [the `find` command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html):

> `-exec  utility_name  [argument ...] ;`
> `-exec  utility_name  [argument ...]   {} +`
>
> The end of the primary expression shall be punctuated by a `<semicolon>` or by a `<plus-sign>`. Only a `<plus-sign>` that immediately follows an argument containing only the two characters `{}` shall punctuate the end of the primary expression. Other uses of the `<plus-sign>` shall not be treated as special.

A more generic solution would possibly be

```
find ... -exec sh -c 'cp "$@" /tmp/dest' sh {} +
```

Here, an inline `sh -c` script is executed with batches of arguments from `find`.  Inside the inline script, `"$@"` will be the list of passed arguments (individually quoted), which allows us to place them as we want them on the `cp` command line.

This allows us to use non-GNU `cp` (on e.g. macOS or other BSD systems, where there is no `-t` option) or any other utility where one may want to add other arguments to the end of the list of pathnames coming from `find`.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find/389706#389706)

---

Nobody asked for this, but anyway...

With the destination directory in a variable, `destdir`:

```
destdir=/tmp/dest

find ... -exec sh -c 'destdir=$1; shift; cp "$@" "$destdir"' sh "$destdir" {} +
```

Note that the `destdir` in the shell calling `find` is a separate variable to the `destdir` in the `sh -c` script.

Or, with `bash`:

```
destdir=/tmp/dest

find ... -exec bash -c 'cp "${@:2}" "$1"' bash "$destdir" {} +
```

This is "slicing" the `"$@"` list to rearrange it appropriately for the `cp` command line, without extracting `$1`, the destination directory pathname, into a separate variable.

Comment: Why does `sh` occur twice in the arguments to `-exec`?

Comment: @gerrit The second `sh` is what is placed in `$0` in the in-line script. It's an arbitrary string used in any error message produced by the `sh -c` shell. Without it, the first argument would end up in `$0` and would not have been copied with `cp` (since `$0` is not part of `"$@"`).

Comment: It should be noted that any non-special character or string is suitable as the second `sh`

Comment: @nezabudka One could also note that `sh` is probably the most relevant string to put there as it is used in error messages produced by that shell, just like it would have been had you executed a shell script instead.

Comment: @gerrit [What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)

Comment: See also `find -exec sh -c 'exec cp...' sh {} +` for those `sh` implementations that don't optimise out the fork by themselves. `bash` (and a few other shells) doesn't optimise out the fork in the `sh -c 'destdir=$1; ...; cp...'` case.